# Unity FireBase Real time DB get All child of a specific Key

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure

```
Root:
   Requests:
        {User_ID1}:
                 Request type1: 
                         Name: data
                 Request type2:
        {User_ID2}:
```

What I want is to get all child of some User ID
something like:

```
     Database.RootReference.Child("Requests").Child("User_ID1");
```

this should return

```
      Request type1: 
             Name: data
      Request type2:**
```

How to achieve this c# for Unity

// SORRY

```
      Database.RootReference.Child("Requests").Child("User_ID1");
```

Working fine but I had a variable for the user ID which was holding a wrong value, for that my code was not working

Answer (score 0):

```
Database.RootReference.Child("Requests").Child("User_ID1");
```

is a correct answer as I mentioned in the question